# Android GL ES2 buffer issue: garbled data

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer, glsurfaceview

I am trying to save whatever is rendered on screen in a Open GL ES2 application, by not calling glClear on a renderbuffer or the framebuffer.

This has been working fine on a physical Nook Color.  But when running on physical Nexus One (running android 2.3.6), I a getting issues where the content of the buffer is garbled after the first render.  For illustration purpose, the screens below shows how the same code looks like in Nexus One and Nook Color.  The code is almost verbatim from com.example.android.apis.graphics.GLES20TriangleRenderer (level 8 example source code set).

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.apis.graphics;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.android.apis.R;

class GLES20TriangleRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

public GLES20TriangleRenderer(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mTriangleVerticesData.length
            * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    // Ignore the passed-in GL10 interface, and use the GLES20
    // class's static methods instead.
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    checkGlError("glUseProgram");

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
    float angle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mMMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
    // Ignore the passed-in GL10 interface, and use the GLES20
    // class's static methods instead.
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
    // Ignore the passed-in GL10 interface, and use the GLES20
    // class's static methods instead.
    mProgram = createProgram(mVertexShader, mFragmentShader);
    if (mProgram == 0) {
        return;
    }
    maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
    checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
    if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
    }
    maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
    checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
    if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
    }

    muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
    if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
    }

    /*
     * Create our texture. This has to be done each time the
     * surface is created.
     */

    int[] textures = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

    mTextureID = textures[0];
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);

    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GLES20.GL_REPEAT);

    InputStream is = mContext.getResources()
        .openRawResource(R.raw.robot);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // Ignore.
        }
    }

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();

    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

private int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if (shader != 0) {
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        int[] compiled = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
        if (compiled[0] == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
            Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
            shader = 0;
        }
    }
    return shader;
}

private int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
    if (vertexShader == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
    if (pixelShader == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    if (program != 0) {
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
        int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
        if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
            Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
            program = 0;
        }
    }
    return program;
}

private void checkGlError(String op) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.e(TAG, op + ": glError " + error);
        throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
    }
}

private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;
private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
        // X, Y, Z, U, V
        -1.0f, -0.5f, 0, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -0.5f, 0, 1.5f, -0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.11803399f, 0, 0.5f,  1.61803399f };

private FloatBuffer mTriangleVertices;

private final String mVertexShader =
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
    "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
    "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;\n" +
    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
    "void main() {\n" +
    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
    "  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n" +
    "}\n";

private final String mFragmentShader =
    "precision mediump float;\n" +
    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
    "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
    "void main() {\n" +
    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
    "}\n";

private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mProjMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mMMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mVMatrix = new float[16];

private int mProgram;
private int mTextureID;
private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
private int maPositionHandle;
private int maTextureHandle;

private Context mContext;
private static String TAG = "GLES20TriangleRenderer";
```

}

The difference is that I removed the glClear call so it becomes like this:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    // Ignore the passed-in GL10 interface, and use the GLES20
    // class's static methods instead.
    //GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);// | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

That code basically rotates the rectangle in the center.  I have also tried rendering to a texture renderbuffer and then rendering the renderbuffer texture and encountered the same result (the render buffer gets garbled after the first call to GLES20.glDrawArrays with the result looking pretty much identical to the bad screenshot).

I'm new to ES2.  What am I doing wrong?

Bad (on Nexus One): http://www.putpix.com/b/files/2849/devicebad.png

Good (on Nook Color): http://www.putpix.com/b/files/2849/devicegood.png

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call clear, the result is undefined.

In particular, the screen is often double-buffered so your program will be seeing multiple buffers presented at different times. There's also no obligation that the buffers are *ever* the same ones you've seen before.